# Problem with tikz using \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hi!
I tried to make this graph with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{schemata}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}}{}{}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};

\draw[-latex,black] (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,1);
\draw[-latex,black] (axis cs:-3,0) -- (axis cs:-3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

But I get the following error.

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.\pgfcrdmth@x \draw[-latex,black] (axis cs:3,0)

Help!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You're not using an `axis` environment (from `pgfplots`), so the `axis cs` doesn't make any sense. Beyond that, just pick useful coordinates for your lines, and add nodes similar to what you did for your axes.

You also have an extra `\end{tikzpicture}` (and `\begin{document}` is missing).

(1/3 and 2/3 are wrong in the image, but correct in the code.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % instead of the manual fix

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};

\draw[-latex,black] (3,0) node[below]{$\gamma_{11}$} -- (3,1) node[right] {1/3};
\draw[-latex,black] (1,0) node[below]{$\gamma_{12}$} -- (1,2) node[right] {2/3};

\draw [<->] (1,0.5) -- node[above] {7} (3,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```